# How to efficiently synchronize rarely changed data?

Tags: java, thread-synchronization

I have a class member that is frequently read from one thread but rarely updated from another thread. How do I efficiently synchronize access to it? I imagine that if I just synchronize every read and write most read synchronizations will be wasted since the object doesn't change between them.

Including code example although it's pretty simple:

```
public class A {

    public static class B {
    }

    private List<B> bs =
        new ArrayList<>();

    public void addB(B b) {
        synchronized (this) {
            bs.add(b);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            List<B> bs;
            synchronized (this) {
                bs = new ArrayList<>(this.bs);
            }
            bs.forEach(b -> { /* do something */ });
        }
    }
}
```

assuming `addB` and `run` run from different threads.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `ReadWriteLock`

You can use `ReadWriteLock`:

```java
ReadWriteLock lock=new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

//Read access:
try{
    lock.readLock().lock();
    //Read access here
}finally{
    lock.readLock().unlock()
}

//Write access
try{
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    //Write access here
}finally{
    lock.writeLock().unlock()
```

This should minimize the overhead on readers as nothing is blocked when reading only.

#### `synchronized`

Another possibility is intrinsic synchronisation:

```java
synchronized(LOCK){
    //Read or write access here
}
```

If most of the work is done in a single thread and there is just a single reader thread (like in your scenario), this would be the most perfornant solution.

#### Use thread-safe classes

A third option could be to use thread safe data classes/data structures. This would not require you to do any synchronization by yourself. In your case, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` would be a good option. It is optimized for many read and rare write accesses.

```java
public class A {

    public static class B {
    }

    private List<B> bs =
        new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();//important

    public void addB(B b) {
        //No synchronized needed
        bs.add(b);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            //No synchronized block needed, just iterate over bs as it is thread safe
            bs.forEach(b -> { /* do something */ });
        }
    }
}
```

---

Whatever you choose, you should measure the performance impact if you care about it.

For measuring performance, you can use tools like JMH.

Comment: Is the reading synchronization part of a ```ReadWriteLock``` more efficient than the mutual exclusion lock such as ```synchronized``` considering I'm not interested in multiple reading concurrency?

Comment: @DaniilLantukhov Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html), it is explained there. In a ReadWriteLock, readers do not block each other.

Comment: That's the irrelevant part. I have one writer thread and one reader thread.

Comment: Yes, `synchronised` is more performant in that case.

Comment: I added other possibilities based on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReentrantReadWriteLock from the concurrent package.